# Heat Equation with Measure as Initial Data

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, geometric-measure-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

In a paper that I am reading, the author uses measures as initial data for pdes. The setting is as following: Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set with smooth boundary. Let $u_0$  be a nonnegative measure on $\Omega$. Let $u$ be the solution of the problem
\begin{align}
u_t - \Delta u &= f(x,t) & &\text{on } \Omega\times(0,\infty),\\
u&=0 & &\text{on }\partial\Omega\times(0,\infty), \\
u &= u_0 & &\text{for a.e. $x$ in $\Omega$},
\end{align}
where $f$ is a globally Lipschitz continuous function.

The author uses the properties of $u$, as I would if $u_0\in L^\infty(\Omega)$. For instance he even uses the convolution of $u_0$ with the Green function for the heat equation, i.e., $$\int_\Omega G(x,y,t) u_0(y) dy.$$

But I don't even know how to think of a solution $u$ where $u_0$ is a measure. How do I show that such a solution $u$ exists, is regular, etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use the integral definition of “solution”. It makes sense even if $u_0$ is a measure.

Comment: It makes sense to allow the initial distribution of heat to be a finite measure, for example.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts but how do I interpret $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ for almost every $x\in\Omega$? $u_0$ is a measure so it is not defined for single points $x\in \Omega$.

Comment: @SC2020 : You cannot measure heat at a point either. Heat is measured over a small region, and that is well-represented as a measure. So integrating against a measure makes sense: $\int_{\Omega}G(x,y,t)d\mu_0(y)dy$. Then $\int_{\Omega'}u(x,y,t)dxdy$ will have a limit of $\mu(\Omega')$ as $t\downarrow 0$. It is a weak limit of measures. In this context, a heat distribution is represented as a measure, and those measures tend weakly to the original measure at $t=0$ as $t\downarrow 0$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Can I also interpret $u=u_0$ as $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \int_\Omega u(x,t) \phi(x) dx = \int_{\Omega} \phi \, u_0(dx)$ for every $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$?

Comment: That should work.

Comment: @SC2020 Could you please share the particular paper if possible?